# What is this equation used for? $\gamma^\mu(i\partial_\mu-eA_\mu)\psi=m\psi$

Tags: schroedinger-equation

As perhaps a mathematical scavenger hunt, my mother (knowing my interest in physics and math equations), sent me this image out of curiosity for what it was.

[image: mystery equation]

Here is the same equation taken from the image:

$$\gamma^\mu(i\partial_\mu-eA_\mu)\psi=m\psi$$

I've attempted to reverse image search it to no avail. With it's resemblance to the Schrödinger equation, I assume it lies within the realms of physics, as for why I've asked this here, rather than math.stackexhcange.

Is anyone familiar with it?

Edit: I don't know where the image is from either.

Comment: This is the dirac equation sourced by a EM-field.
See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the Schrodinger equation because it is the interacting Dirac equation. Dirac discovered the Dirac equation as a relativistic Schrodinger equation.
$$ (i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)\psi = 0. $$
He added the electric field $A_\mu$, finding an equation which perfectly (to experimental accuracy) models the electron in an electromagnetic field. The prediction for the gyromagnetic moment agrees with observation to one part in $10^{12}$.

Comment: Fascinating, thank you for elaborating

Comment: 1. $A_\mu$ is not the electric field, it is the 4-potential whose derivatives give rise to the electric field. 2. The gyromagnetic moment agreeing to one part in $10^{12}$ is a result of quantisation applied to the Dirac equation - on its own it does not achieve that precision.

Answer (score 3):

It's the Dirac equation (RQM) for a fast charged particle in an EM field

Comment: Just a little detail, i would specify *fermion* rather than a general particle

Comment: It is also written in a form that leads to a local gauge invariant Lagrangian.